# Show that a complex function is not injective in any neighborhood of the origin

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have the following function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}  $

$$f(z)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
z\left(1+2\left | z \right | \sin \frac{1}{\left | z \right |}\right) & z \neq 0,\\ 
0 & z=0.
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Show that it is not injective in any neighborhood  of the origin.

**Steps:**

The truth is that I have not yet reached these non-intensive points but given $r > 0$ then by Archimedes' principle there is always a natural number $k$ such that $\frac{1}{2k\pi } < r$.

Then taking $|z| = \frac{1}{2k\pi}$, we have $f(z) = z (1 + 0)= z$.

I was trying to find points such that they are not injective but I did not get anywhere. Any idea about ​​how I can solve it?

Comment: Notice that the restriction of $f$ to the real interval $(0,\varepsilon)$ is differentiable with derivative $1+4x\sin\frac1x-2\cos\frac1x$ and, therefore, not monotone.